# How to do server side rendering in react despite all react router version conflicts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to server-side rendering with react and react-router-dom I've done this before but with the new version, it is throwing me an error **You should not use Switch outside a Router** I think it is a version conflict but is there a solution ([react-router-config - You should not use  outside a  (it is inside a Router!)](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6679)).

server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import App from '../client/src/AppRoutes';
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { renderRoutes } from 'react-router-config'


const app = express();



app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    const routerContext = {};
    res.send(`
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>SSR</head>
      <body>
        <div id="root">${ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
            <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={routerContext}>
                    <div>{renderRoutes(App)}</div>
            </StaticRouter>
            )}</div>
<!--        <script src="/dist/main.js"></script>-->
      </body>
    </html>
  `);
});


app.listen(3000, (error) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.log('something bad happened', error);
    }
    console.log("listening on " + 3000 + "...");
});
```

AppRoutes.js

```
import PageA from './Container/PageA';
import PageB from './Container/PageB';
import Home from './Container/Home'
import MainPage from './Container/MainPage';



export default [
    {
        ...MainPage,
        routes:[
            {
              ...Home,
              path:'/',
              exact:true
            },
            {
                ...PageA,
                path:'/a',
                exact:true
            },
            {
                ...PageB,
                path:'/b',
                exact:true

            }
        ]
    }
]
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "reactSSRwithCodeSplitting",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "babel-node server/index.js",
    "start": "nodemon server/index.js",
    "build": "babel server --out-dir ./dist --source-maps",
    "serve": "node ./dist/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-loadable": "^5.5.0",
    "react-router-config": "^5.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/node": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "*",
    "@babel/register": "^7.5.5",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: I know it could be a little too much to ask for, but could you set up a https://codesandbox.io so we can test and fix? Anyways it seems like it could be [versioning of react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6679#issuecomment-514682011)?

Answer (score 0):

#### Quick fix:

1. Remove your `node_modules`
2. Add `"react-router": "^5.0.1"` to your `package.json`
3. Re-install with `npm install`.

Ensure that `react-router`, `react-router-config`, `react-router-dom` are in the same version.

#### What is wrong?

When I try to reproduce your error, I figure out that your `package.json` in the question is missing `react-router` dependency, which makes me unable to start the server.

And from your story, I guess that you have another version of `react-router` in your `node_modules`, which is out of sync with `react-router-config` and `react-router-dom` version 5.0.1.

So I try to reproduce the problem with this:

```
"react-router": "^4.3.0",
"react-router-config": "^5.0.1",
"react-router-dom": "^5.0.1"
```

Which will lead to the problem you mentioned.

Comment: I made all the changes but still, I am getting this error ```Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Switch> outside a <Router>```

Comment: @Nane you're the owner of this question? Do you have any sandbox or source code so that I can reproduce errors?